# Is the following Fourier Transform in cylindrical coordinates correct?

Tags: fourier-transform, polar-coordinates, integral-transforms, cylindrical-coordinates

I am trying to solve the integral $$\int_ {Cylinder}e^{-i\vec{k}\vec{r}}dV=\int_0^Rrdr\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^Le^{-ik_zz}e^{-i(k_xx+k_yy)}dz$$
I tried to rewrite it using polar coordinates and solved it using Mathematica:
$$\int_0^Rrdr\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^Le^{-ik_zz}e^{-ik_rr\cos\phi}dz$$ where I used that $k_xx+k_yy = |k_r||r|\cos(\phi)$.

The result, however, is not correct and gives a regularized hypergeometric function and not the expected Bessel function.

Where did I go wrong?

Edit: I have also found various resources citing a so-called Hankel transform, but I have never heard of it before.

Comment: Have you tried $$\int_ {Cylinder}e^{-i\vec{k}\vec{r}}dV=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^Rrdr\int_0^Le^{-ik_zz}e^{-i(k_xx+k_yy)}dz$$?

Comment: Hm here I run into troubles with Mathematica as $k_x, k_y$ are my integration variables and they do not coincide with the integral bounds.

Comment: Using Mathematica? But is the Fourier transform above correct? It seems like so, I just took a look at [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241069465_Two-Dimensional_Fourier_Transforms_in_Polar_Coordinates) paper

Comment: Let me  check this thoroughly again

Comment: This is what I did, put 

\begin{equation}
\int_0^L e^{(-ik_zz)}e^{(-ik_xrcos\phi)}e^{(ik_yrsin\phi)}dz=\frac{1}{k_z}\bigg(-(i e^{(-i (k_z L + k_x r \cos\phi) - k_y r \sin\phi))} )(-1 + e^{(i k_z L)})\bigg)
\end{equation} But then, integrating this on rdr from 0 to R does not work on wolfram alpha. Can you try to integrate this with Mathematica? It works there, but it is awfully long and not converted to TEX.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did, put $x=r\cos\phi$ and  $y=r\sin\phi$:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^L e^{(-ik_zz)}e^{(-ik_xrcos\phi)}e^{(ik_yrsin\phi)}dz=\frac{1}{k_z}\bigg(-(i e^{(-i (k_z L + k_x r \cos\phi) - k_y r \sin\phi))} )(-1 + e^{(i k_z L)})\bigg)
\end{equation}

This is then integrated on dr:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^R \frac{1}{k_z}\bigg(-(i e^{(-i (k_z L + k_x r \cos\phi) - k_y r \sin\phi))} )(-1 + e^{(i k_z L)})\bigg)rdr
\end{equation}

and it gives:

\begin{equation}
\frac{(e^{-i (k_z L+b R \cos\phi -k_y R +\sin\phi)} (-1+e^{i k_z L}) (k_x R \cos\phi+i (-1+e^{i R
(k_x \cos\phi -k_y \sin\phi)}+i k_y R \sin\phi)))}{(k_z (k_x \cos\phi -k_y \sin\phi^2))}
\end{equation}

Then you do the $d\phi$ integration. But Mathematica does not seem to solve that.

Comment: Yes, its super weird, Mathematica doesn't solve the integral. But also, I found [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241069465_Two-Dimensional_Fourier_Transforms_in_Polar_Coordinates) paper (eq. 7) defining the integral as $...e^{-ik_r r \cos(k_{\phi} - \phi)}...$ instead of $...e^{-ik_r r \cos(\phi)}...$. Where does that extra term come from?

Comment: It seems like the same function only it is shifted by $k_\phi$. I can't tell why they do that. It is better to stick to the standard definition, for simplicity. Have you asked on Mathematica Stackexchange for that last integral?